# PHP. How to extract array keys for new array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I extract `server_vps_de_dc1_s1` from this array:

```
$server = array(    
    "vps" => array (        
        "de" => array (     
            "dc1" => array (                
                "s1" => array (                 
                    "name"=>    "Xen VPS 200",
                    "processor"=>   "200 MHz",
                    "memory"=>  "200 MB",
                ),                  
            ),              
        ),              
    ),              
    "dedicated" => array (      
        ...
    ),    
);
```

to build new array that should looks like this one:

```
$server_id = array(    
    "1" => "server_vps_de_dc1_s1",
    "2" => "server_vps_de_dc1_s2",
    "3" => "server_vps_de_dc2_s1",
    "4" => "server_vps_usa_dc1_s1",
    ...
);
```

Comment: You're going to have to use a lot of loops. You should consider refactoring your code; this looks suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need recursion:

```
function get_keys( $array)
{
    if( !is_array( $array)) 
        return array();
    $k = key( $array);
    return array_merge( array( $k), get_keys( $array[$k]));
}
```

You'd invoke it like this:

```
$keys = get_keys( $array);
array_pop( $keys); // Get rid of the last key:
```

And you get as output:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "vps" [1]=> string(2) "de" [2]=> string(3) "dc1" [3]=> string(2) "s1" }
```

Which you can form your new values with `implode()`:

```
$new_value = implode( '_', $keys); // Outputs "vps_de_dc1_s1"
```

[Demo](http://viper-7.com/oLIELj)